# Quantity selector for each variant that manages to track a min and max sharedquantity then make options visible based on the shared quantity selected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to implement a quantity selector system for each variant of my product that manages to track a minimum and maximum shared quantity for all variants, and then make options visible based on the shared quantity selected.

F.e

Red t-shirt (quantity input)
Green t-shirt (quantity input)

Total: 1-9 -> options (es. "print type A" that costs X)

Total: 10-19 -> options (es "print type B" that costs Y)

I'm using tm-extra-options for options